The works of Frontier Manufacturing
Having spent the last however many decades believing Commodore Semiconductor Group was a simple rename of MOS Technology, I just watched a video – quite interesting in its own right – which casually remarks that this is not so; it's a collective name for all the semiconductor companies that CBM bought.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBXOiRinvaw&list=WL&index=10&ab_channel=CommodoreHistory
Relevant remark is around 2:40.
And Google turns up a handful of results that seem to confirm this is the case, but I have not yet found any further detail.
One of the companies in question was called Frontier Manufacturing, in Los Angeles.
What did they do? What chips did they design or make, either before or after the acquisition? Much has been said and written about the central importance of MOS Technology in the history of Commodore as a computer company; almost no one seems to have even heard of Frontier Manufacturing, and no one seems to have anything to say about them. But they must have done something?

They could have been a packaging house, or printed circuit board house, up to and including fully populated boards or even boards stuffed in housings. A lot happens between making a chip and delivering a computer to a customer.

If someone has access to the Stanford library they could access (by request) their collection of the Western Electronic Manufacturers Association directories from 1960 to 1977 (https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/9863995)
